# When requesting azure TTS through the ssml statement, there is a delay of about 2 seconds

Tags: text-to-speech

As shown in the code below, when azure TTS is requested with the ssml statement, the response is delayed for about 2 seconds.

```
public static async Task SynthesizeAudioAsync()
{
   var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxxxxxxKey", "xxxxxxxRegion");
   using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null);

   var ssml = File.ReadAllText("C:/ssml.xml");
   var result = await synthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(ssml);  <=== The delay is right here
​   using var stream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
   await stream.SaveToWaveFileAsync("C:/file.wav");
}
```

What is the problem?
Or is it normal for the response speed to be delayed by 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = await synthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(ssml);
```

As far as I know, the time taken would be proportional to the data you have in the ssml for it to be converted speech.

What happens in the backend is that : The ssml data is relayed to Azure Speech Services, azure speech service processes the text, builds the required audio bytes using the ML Model returns to the requesting client.

I am assuming the delay you are talking about is the latency for doing the above process. If the data/text to be recognized is large, there will be considerable time in building required audio bytes.

Since you are using `await`, the code will be waiting until it is completed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The ssml content is about 50 Korean characters. I use neural voice and use the pitch and rate options. I am wondering if the delay response for more than 2 seconds is normal under this condition.